# 504 Gateway Time-out после загрузки файла на сервер (nginx)

Tags: ubuntu, apache, nginx, php-fpm

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема: после загрузки файла на сервер - удаленный - возникла ошибка 504, и не уходит. Файл, к слову, так и не загрузился, но ошибка при этом осталась. Причем показывает на всех страницах. Перепробовал все: от перезагрузки сервера до изменений настроек в конфигурационных файлах. Ничего не помогает. Сервер nginx в связке либо с апаче, либо с php-fpm (и то и другое присутствует на сервере).
К слову, я не админ. К админу невозможно обратиться в виду его недоступности.

Логи error.log

```
2017/11/16 10:04:32 [error] 2743#0: *767 client intended to send too large body: 8498507 bytes, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "POST /frontend_dev.php/material/create HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/material/new"
2017/11/16 12:18:25 [error] 6932#0: *27 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/devel/uploads/almaz/mektep24/apps/frontend/modules/material/actions/actions.class.php:573) in /usr/share/php/symfony/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 336
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/devel/uploads/almaz/mektep24/apps/frontend/modules/material/actions/actions.class.php:573) in /usr/share/php/symfony/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 357" while reading upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/material/files/download/475.html?file=93811dc1a9ccb7315efd205a18ff98dd96604e3a.djvu HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/ru/material/240/show.html"
2017/11/16 12:21:46 [error] 6932#0: *41 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "POST /frontend_dev.php/material/create HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/material/new"
2017/11/16 13:03:17 [error] 6932#0: *43 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/material/new HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/ru/material/list.html"
2017/11/16 13:22:33 [error] 6932#0: *45 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/material/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/ru/material/240/show.html"
2017/11/16 13:23:06 [error] 6932#0: *47 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/school/teachers/meeting/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
2017/11/16 13:29:02 [error] 6932#0: *49 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru_RU/material/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/material/edit/id/240"
2017/11/16 13:56:59 [error] 8259#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/material/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/ru/material/240/show.html"
2017/11/16 13:57:03 [error] 8259#0: *3 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru_RU/material/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/material/edit/id/240"
2017/11/16 13:57:07 [error] 8259#0: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/school/teachers/meeting/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
2017/11/16 15:24:47 [error] 8259#0: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/school/teachers/meeting/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
2017/11/16 15:35:32 [error] 8259#0: *9 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/school/teachers/meeting/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
2017/11/16 15:35:48 [error] 8259#0: *11 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru_RU/material/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/material/edit/id/240"
2017/11/16 15:35:50 [error] 8259#0: *13 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/material/list.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090", referrer: "http://192.168.0.100:8090/frontend_dev.php/ru/material/240/show.html"
2017/11/17 09:51:11 [error] 8259#0: *16 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
2017/11/17 10:05:31 [error] 8259#0: *29 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
2017/11/17 13:03:35 [error] 8259#0: *50 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.202, server: tiptar.com, request: "GET /frontend_dev.php/ru/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "192.168.0.100:8090"
```

Логи php5-fpm

```
[16-Nov-2017 12:16:18] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[16-Nov-2017 12:16:18] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 6885
[16-Nov-2017 12:16:18] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[16-Nov-2017 12:16:18] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[16-Nov-2017 13:28:02] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[17-Nov-2017 06:51:40] NOTICE: error log file re-opened
```

Команда рестарт `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart` вызвала ошибку:

```
stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.74" (uid=1002 pid=29023 comm="stop php5-fpm ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.75" (uid=1002 pid=29016 comm="start php5-fpm ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
almaz@devel:/etc/init.d$ /etc/init.d/php5-fpm status
```

Comment: А что пытались загрузить и каким образом? Размер файла какой? `htop` смотрели?

Comment: @Klimenkomud Прошу простить мне мое невежество, я пока новичок в линукс. Пытался загрузить видео (16 Mb). Ранее была проблема с размерами загружаемого файла (больше 1 Мб не принимал), но ее решили прописав в php.ini размеры загружаемых файлов. Запустил `htop`, но то что там вижу ни о чем мне не говорит. https://i.imgur.com/5u4L7Ri.jpg

Comment: Какая ОС стоит?

Comment: покажите логи `nginx'a` (правьте свой вопрос). Логи находятся обычно по пути `/var/log/nginx/log_file`.

Comment: @Ep1demic отредактировал, добавил логи.

Comment: @Klimenkomud Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-77-generic x86_64)

Comment: Логи `php-fpm` ещё добавьте, кажется он у вас помер

Comment: И попробуйте `sudo systemctl php-fpm status`, добавьте в ответ что получится. Если не лежит - попробуйте `sudo systemctl php-fpm restart`

Comment: @Klimenkomud `php5-fpm` вроде живой, на `status` пишет `php5-fpm start/running, process 6885`, но на перезагрузку выдает ошибку (добавил в вопрос). На вашу команду выдает `sudo: systemctl: command not found`

Comment: Ошибки не вижу, `php-fpm` сделал рестарт и "отрапортовал". Попробуйте поправить файл `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` и выставить в `pm.max_children` больше значение. Не знаю сколько оптимально, но 30 - 40 вместо пяти должно помочь. И не забудьте рестартануть `php-fpm`

Comment: И да, очень странно что `systemctl` на сервере не стоит.

Comment: Загрузка файла ни при чём. Когда в логах 504 ошибка -- это значит, что ресурсов бекенду не хватает и пора увеличить. Без сисадмина вы сами вряд ли справитесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Перепробовал все: от перезагрузки сервера до изменений настроек в
>   конфигурационных файлах

Что вы там "крутили" в настройках, скорее всего вы и сами не понимали.

Далее

> 017 13:28:02] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children
>   setting (5), consider raising it

Вот уже нам пишется в логах, что нужно исправлять и в чем одна из проблем.

Пробуем, в зависимости от дистра, править `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (это для Deb, Ubuntu) изменив эти параметры:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 30 
pm.start_servers = 3 
pm.min_spare_servers = 2 
pm.max_spare_servers = 4 
pm.max_requests = 500 ##раскоментируйте эту строку
```

И перезапускам php-fpm `>sudo systemctl restart php5-fpm` или, раз вы пишете,

> sudo: systemctl: command not found

командой  `>sudo service restart php5-fpm`

Запускаем опять загрузку файла, или что там у вас, когда выдает 504. И если все "ок" - радуемся).

Если нет, опять смотрим логи. Смотрим что они вам пишут.

Как вариант, можно попробовать подправить конфиг nginx. Судя по тому, что он у вас стоит перед апачем, смотри секцию server, и приводим её к примерно такому виду:

```
server {
...
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
...
}
```

и перезапускаем nginx, скорее всего для вашего случая
`>sudo service restart nginx`

Тестируем...

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Помогло редактирование файла `www.conf`

Comment: Привет! Раз помогло) - пометьте вопрос-ответ, как решенный)